# jQuery Keydown event not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, keydown

I am using the following JQuery code to capture keydown events in a DIV:

```
$("#pnlPreview").keydown(pnlPreview_onKeyDown);
```

The specific keydown combinations I am trying to capture are these:

- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>INSERT</kbd>
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>DELETE</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>INSERT</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>DELETE</kbd>

While this code works fine in IE, it does not work in Chrome. I am using the latest Chrome browser (38.0.2125.104) under Windows 7.

Can someone please tell me how to capture these keydown combinations in Google Chrome?

See this jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/fx7do2cf/7. This most closely duplicates what I have in my project. Key down events are detected in IE and not detected in Chrome.

Comment: show us your code please.

Comment: Seems to be working fine http://jsfiddle.net/1b4re4nm/1/

Comment: I verified your jsfiddle Spokey.  Let me investigate further to see what the difference is in my project.

Comment: Spokey, I modified your jsfiddle slightly to match my case. In this case I am setting the keydown event on the div id (not the document) and then setting the focus to the div. See http://jsfiddle.net/yL67u5th/.

Comment: I think the problem may be that chrome doesn't fire the event on elements that are not editable or some focus problems. Setting tabindex seems to help http://jsfiddle.net/yL67u5th/1/. Focus shouldn't work in IE without tabindex either

Comment: Spokey: See this jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/fx7do2cf/7. This most closely duplicates what I have in my project. Key down events are detected in IE and not detected in Chrome.

Comment: It appears that Chrome is not respecting z-index, so because div3 is contained within div1, div3 is not getting focus for this reason.

Comment: Elements that are not selectable or editable cannot be focused so you have to set tabindex http://jsfiddle.net/8ac8xu2b/ or http://jsfiddle.net/fx7do2cf/12/. This is also stated in the api docu http://api.jquery.com/focus/. Just because it works in IE doesn't mean it'll work everywhere

Comment: Very good, Spokey. I notice that when tabindex='0' is put in the html it works in Chrome but when I remove it from the html and instead put tabindex: 0; or tabindex: '0'; in the css it does not work in Chrome.  Can you explain why it does not work the same if the tabindex attribute is in the css instead of the html? See http://jsfiddle.net/fx7do2cf/23/ and http://jsfiddle.net/fx7do2cf/24/.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63554/discussion-between-obi-wan-and-spokey).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real issue was not that Chrome was not capturing the keydown events but instead it was that focus cannot be set to div in Chrome without having the tabIndex attribute on the div.  Although focus can be set to the div without the tabindex attribute in IE, in Chrome it cannot be set.

All credit for solving this issue should go to Spokey. He was instrumental in determining the real issue and in solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make keydown event as

```
$(document).on("keydown",'<selector>',function(event){
  alert("You clicked " + event.keyCode);
  // code
})
```

For the above case use

```
$(document).on("keydown",'#pnlPreview', pnlPreview_onKeyDown);
```